# How to sort only own webform submissions in a view?

Tags: 7, views, webforms, users

I have a view that lists all users webform submissions.

I want to be able to have the view show the name of the user instead of his id and display only his own webform submissions.

**Image-1**

> [image: view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to specify as Filter criteria "webform submission:user " and in fields I added the same criteria. Then I customized it by creating a label name.

The video tutorial [Drupal Views Module: Creating lists of content on your Drupal site](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K6q6VztC6HM) really helped me discovering [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) and find an answer to my question (I recommend it for every beginners like me).

Comment: You should not post an answer with a link only.

Comment: Sorry, i did not know, well the solution for my case, i specify as  Filter criteria "webform submission:user "  and in fields i add the same criteria and i customize it by creating a label name.

Comment: You can just update your answer rather leaving it in comment :)